# Unable to use async in forEach loop inside an API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a get API call which looks like this

```
router.get('/review', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const entity = await Entity.find();
    const entityId = [];
    Object.keys(entity).forEach((key) => {
      entityId.push(entity[key]._id);
    });
    const results = [];
    Object.keys(entityId).forEach(async (key) => {
      const reviews = await Review.find({ entityId: entityId[key] });
      results.push(reviews);
    });

    res.send(results);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
});
```

In `entityId` array it has a list of all the id i need and till there it works. Now what I want to do is iterate over each id of `entityId` and find the corresponding review that the entity has, push those review into a `results` array and return `results`.

`review` has an `entityId` field which is same as `id` of `entity`.

I also looked at - [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

which suggested to use for loop but it gave the following error.

```
iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favor of array iterations.eslintno-restricted-syntax
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use promises instead of foreach.

Thy this

```
const data = async () => {
  const entity = {
    a: { _id: "1231" },
    b: { _id: "1232" },
    c: { _id: "1233" }
  };

  const entityId = [];
  Object.keys(entity).forEach(key => {
    entityId.push(entity[key]._id);
  });
  const promise = [];
  Object.keys(entityId).forEach(async key => {
    const reviews = Review({ entityId: entityId[key] });
    promise.push(reviews);
  });
  const results = await Promise.all(promise);
};

const Review = (option) => {
  return true;
};

data();
```

Answer (score 2):

forEach does not respect await therefore it may result in unintentional behaviour
you can use map to return array of promises from **Review.find()** and wrap those in await Promise.all({promises array here}) and use **await** on Promise.all.
This will result in parallel calls instead of doing them sequentially one after another.

```
const promisesWoAwait = this.entityIds.map(entityId => Review.find({ entityId }));

const result = await Promise.all(promisesWoAwait);
```